# compare two XML files

Tags: diff, xml

Is there a possibility that we can compare two xml files and identify the differences in them. And then get the out put to a output new file.

I used `diff xml1 xml2` but this gives me only differences in lines, what i am looking is for the differences from tree level.

Comment: what should be the diff output if 2 files have the same structure but different attribute value on some nested tag?

Answer (score 3):

[diffxml](http://diffxml.sourceforge.net/) is one tool that does this and [xmldiff](https://www.logilab.org/project/xmldiff) another. Both of them have options for choosing what you want to consider a difference, and produce structured output. With `diffxml` you get an XML file describing the necessary transformations in detail, and with `xmldiff` either a list of XSL selectors and what to do with them or an XML file in [xupdate format](http://xmldb-org.sourceforge.net/xupdate/xupdate-wd.html).

There are also libraries for [PHP](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/xmldiff-file.diff.php), [Perl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Diff/Diff.pm), [Perl again](http://search.cpan.org/~khampton/XML-SemanticDiff-0.95/SemanticDiff.pm), [Python](https://github.com/cfpb/xtdiff), [C#](https://www.nuget.org/packages/XMLDiffPatch/), ..., which you could use to build something giving whatever exact behaviour you wanted.